# im trying to add 1 to the x variable each time the mouse is clicked, but instead it adds 7 or more when i left click

Tags: python-3.x, mouse

look this is my code

```
import mouse
x = 0
while True:
    if mouse.is_pressed("left"):
        x = x+1
        print(x)
```

every time i make a single click it detects as if i had made a lot of clicks, i think it may be some sort of typo, im new to python

this is how the output looks

```
Python 3.7.2 (tags/v3.7.2:9a3ffc0492, Dec 23 2018, 22:20:52) [MSC v.1916 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> 
================== RESTART: C:\Users\Liam\Desktop\clickspersecond.py ==================
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I see as the flaw in the logic you've written out.
When you're pressing the mouse button, the while loop reads an x + 1 event every time it ticks over and the mouse button is still depressed.

I'd suggest adding a change_state flag for your mouse press event.

```
import mouse
mouse_click_recorded: bool = False
num_of_clicks = 0

while True:
    if not mouse_click_recorded and mouse.is_pressed("left"):
        num_of_clicks += 1
        mouse_click_recorded = True
    if mouse_click_recorded and not mouse.is_pressed("left"):
        mouse_click_recorded = False

print(num_of_clicks)
```

Comment: It works kind of bad, I have to wait a while between each click, but thanks anyway

Comment: if you're going to work inside a while loop in python you're going to have those limitations. If you want something snappier, I'd go for something in async python